# Find Stopping Criterion Based On The Arguments Used In The Proof of Banach’s Theorem for Bisection Method

Tags: python, numerical-methods, bisection

We were asked the following question:
Write pseudocode to implement the bisection method on f given in
question 1. You should include a stopping criterion based on the arguments used in the proof of Banach’s theorem.

Question 1 is given as: Consider the function f(x) = x^3 − 3. Approximate the root of f using
three iterations of the following methods.
(a) The bisection method on the line segment [1, 2];

The proof of Banach's Fixed point theorem is given as:

Proof Pt.1

[image: Proof Pt.1]

Proof Pt.2

[image: Proof Pt.2]

I have no clue how to find the stopping criterion for the bisection method from the proof of Banach's Fixed Point Theorem.